# Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewCellRenderer.GetCell Exception: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Has anyone experienced the following problem when using a `ViewCellRenderer` in Xamarin.Forms?

I am trying to add a Disclosure Indicator to my Xamarin.Forms custom `ViewCell` via a Custom Renderer.

When `base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv)` gets called in the Custom Renderer, it triggers an Exception: `Specified cast is not valid`.

I am using Xamarin.Forms v2.3.3.175.

## ViewCell Renderer

```
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using SampleApp;
using SampleApp.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PriceControlViewCell), typeof(PriceControlViewCellCustomRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class PriceControlViewCellCustomRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

## ViewCell

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class PriceControlViewCell : TextCell
    {
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();

            Text = "";
            Detail = "";

            var item = BindingContext as PriceControlModel;

            Text = "Configuration Id";
            Detail = item.ConfigurationId.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

## Stack Trace

```
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Cells\ViewCellRenderer.cs:13 
  at SampleApp.iOS.PriceControlViewCellCustomRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv) [0x00005] in /Users/brandonm/Projects/GitHub/SampleApp/iOS/CustomRenderers/PriceControlViewCellCustomRenderer.cs:16 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CellTableViewCell.GetNativeCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell, System.Boolean recycleCells, System.String templateId) [0x00086] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Cells\CellTableViewCell.cs:74 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00060] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:727 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at SampleApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00035] in /Users/brandonm/Projects/GitHub/SampleApp/iOS/Main.cs:25
```

Comment: I'll update my answer if you can post w/e the source to PriceControlViewCell is and show that it's a valid `ViewCell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your code being used for whatever `PriceControlViewCell` is. My guess is that it's not a `ViewCell` since [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/ViewCellRenderer.cs#L9) is failing:

```
var viewCell = (ViewCell)item;
```

UPDATE:

Use `PriceControlViewCell : ViewCell` instead of `PriceControlViewCell : TextCell`. `TextCell` inherits from `Cell`, same as `ViewCell` and is not `TextCell : ViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks John! I added my ViewCell implementation, and I think I'm seeing the problem: Am I not allowed to use a TextCell with a ViewCellRenderer?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem, and found that there is `TextCellRenderer`. All I had to do was change the base class of the custom renderer. In your case, this would mean instead of

```
public class PriceControlViewCellCustomRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
```

use this:

```
public class PriceControlViewCellCustomRenderer : TextCellRenderer
```

The rest of the code can remain unchanged. Tested successfully on an iPhone 5 built with Visual Studio 15 with Xamarin 4.5.
I also proposed this as a solution [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18131/listview-cell-arrow-disclosure-indicator), because their original Todo sample has the once recommended hack for the disclosure indicator commented out.